# Searching multi-valued fields in the same position

Tags: solr

Let's say we have a document like this:

```
<arr name="pvt_rate_type">
  <str>CORPORATE</str>
  <str>AGENCY</str>
</arr>

<arr name="pvt_rate_set_id">
  <str>1</str>
  <str>2</str>
</arr>
```

Now I do a search where I want to return the document only if it contains pvt_rate_set_id = 1 AND pvt_rate_type = AGENCY in the same position in their mutli-valued fields so the above document should NOT be returned (because pvt_rate_set_id 1 has a pvt_rate_type of CORPORATE)

Is this possible at all in SOLR ? or is my schema badly designed ? how else would you design tat schema to allow for the searching I want?

Comment: How did you do it finally? I am still looking for a solution. Please share if you do have

Answer (score 1):

This may not be available Out of the Box.
You would need to modify the schema to have fields with pvt rate type as field name and id as its value

e.g.

```
CORPORATE=1
AGENCY=2
```

This can be achieved by having [dynamic fields](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#Dynamic_fields) defined.

e.g.

```
<dynamicField name="*_pvt_rate_type"  type="string"  indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
```

So you can input data as corporate_pvt_rate_type or agency_pvt_rate_type with the respective values.

The filter queries will be able to match the exact mappings `fq=corporate_pvt_rate_type:1`

Comment: Ok so we have defined the keys to be from `pvt_rate_type` field. But, don't we need to somewhere specify that the value should be taken from `pvt_rate_set_id` field. How does it work without specifying the other filed? I am slightly confused.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Solr does not seem to support this.

Another way to do this in Solr would be to store a concatenated string field `type_and_id` with a delimiter (say comma) separating the type and the id and query like:

```
q=type_and_id:AGENCY%2C1
```

(where `%2C` is the URL encoding for comma).